# how to multiply object values and retain their keys in ES6

Tags: javascript

I have the following object that holds conversion factors:

```
  const convertToYards =
  {
    "feet": 3,
    "meters": 0.9144,
    "yards": 1
  }
```

Then there is a variable that holds a number like so:
`const maximumYards = 500;`

I am trying to figure out a way to multiply all of the values in `convertToYards` by the number in `maximumYards` so a new object would be created like this:

```
  const maximums =
  {
    "feet": 1500,
    "meters": 457.2,
    "yards": 500
  }
```

I have tried this

```
const maximums = Object.values(convertToYards).map(o => o * maximumYards);
```

but that creates an array rather than an object so it does not carry along the original key names.  How should this be modified to get the desired output?

Comment: If you've found `Object.values()` then you might have also seen `Object.keys()`.

Comment: Or use a plain old `for...in...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it by combining `Object.entries` (to get an array), `map` (to map the values), and `Object.fromEntries` (to get an object again):

```
const maximums = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(convertToYards).map(([name, value]) => [name, value * maximumYards])
);
```

```js
const convertToYards = {
    "feet": 3,
    "meters": 0.9144,
    "yards": 1
};

const maximumYards = 500;

const maximums = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(convertToYards).map(([name, value]) => [name, value * maximumYards])
);

console.log(maximums);
```

Or just use a `for-in` loop; you might need to weed out inherited properties if `convertToYards` may have them, though:

```
const maximums = {};
for (const name in convertToYards) {
    maximums[name] = convertToYards[name] * maximumYards;
}
```

```js
const convertToYards = {
    "feet": 3,
    "meters": 0.9144,
    "yards": 1
};

const maximumYards = 500;

const maximums = {};
for (const name in convertToYards) {
    maximums[name] = convertToYards[name] * maximumYards;
}

console.log(maximums);
```

A middle ground would be to use `keys` with `for-of`:

```
const maximums = {};
for (const name of Object.keys(convertToYards)) {
    maximums[name] = convertToYards[name] * maximumYards;
}
```

```js
const convertToYards = {
    "feet": 3,
    "meters": 0.9144,
    "yards": 1
};

const maximumYards = 500;

const maximums = {};
for (const name of Object.keys(convertToYards)) {
    maximums[name] = convertToYards[name] * maximumYards;
}

console.log(maximums);
```

Comment: or `Object.keys().reduce()`

Comment: @AyushGupta - I'm not a fan of `reduce` outside of functional programming with predefined, reusable, tested reducer functions. Just too hard to read and maintain, too easy to get wrong. Also not a fan of `reduce` when the accumulator value never changes (in this case, it would just always be the same object reference). But yes, it's possible. :-)

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment you can use a plain old `for .. in` as shown in this code snippet:

```
const convertToYards = {
  feet: 3,
  meters: 0.9144,
  yards: 1,
};

let maximums = {};
for (let a in convertToYards) {
  maximums[a] = convertToYards[a] * maximumYards;
}
console.log(maximums);
```